# My FTP server ends connection automatically with client after requesting username and password

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, ftp

So, here's my issue. I am using a Linux built-in client by the way.

I am writing a FTP server (TCP sockets) in C, but before implementing the commands the client needs to ask the user name and password. If they are the same I must grant access to the user. The problem is that as soon as I finish logging in, my server sends a SYST command and stops the connection. In my code I call 220 and 331 to retrieve the user and password respectively, and 230 to grant access.

```
char login_user[BUFSIZ]; // Holds the username
char login_password[BUFSIZ]; //Holds the password
char buff1[BUFSIZ];
char buff2[BUFSIZ];
int x = 0, y = 0, compare = 0;
// Ask for the username   
send(sock, "220\r\n", 5, 0); 
x = read(sock, login_user, sizeof(login_user));
if(x < 0)
    perror("server: can't receive from client");
else
    login_user[x] = '\0';   
strncpy(buff1, login_user + 5, strlen(login_user)-7); //this copies only the username taking out surplus characters


// Ask for password   
send(sock, "331\r\n", 5, 0);
y = read(sock, login_password, sizeof(login_password));
if(y < 0)
    perror("server: can't receive from client");
else
    login_password[y] = '\0';
strncpy(buff2, login_password + 5, strlen(login_password)-7); //this copies only the password taking out surplus characters


// If username and password are the same, grant access, else exit connection
compare = strcmp(buff1, buff2);
printf("%s, %s, %d\n", buff1, buff2, compare);
if(compare == 0)
{
    send(sock, "230\r\n", 5, 0);
}
else
    send(sock, "421\r\n", 5, 0);
```

I was thinking that maybe the problem is my vsftpd.conf file, but local_enable is activated. Any suggestions are welcomed :)

And this is what the client looks like:

user@ubuntu:~$ ftp

ftp> open ubuntu 1111

Connected to ubuntu.

220

Name (ubuntu:user): user

331

Password:

230

421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection

ftp>

Comment: You should run it under a debugger, but all those str* null-terminated string lib calls are worrying.

Comment: So you aren't comparing the passwords correctly, or you sent the wrong one. This is just a trivial C coding issue: you should be able to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: I don't know how to solve it. I need inspiration, namely a coded example.

Comment: Is the above the entirety of your server code?  If so, it suggests that after sending the 230 response code, the server simply exists.  The `ftp` command-line client will often display "421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection" for such abruptly closed connections, even though the remote FTP server never actually _sent_ that 421 message.  You can verify this by using `ftp -d ubuntu 111`; the `-d` will show what actually is received by `ftp` from the server.

Answer (score -1):

NAT-firewall between you and the server showing the symptom.

The problem is like ftp wants to send the data resulting from the command in a new, separate TCP/IP connection and that cannot go through the firewall because it needs to go from the server to you, and you are hidden behind the firewall. Use the "pasv" command to change to a passive connection where data connections to go from you to the server.

For More Detail See : [Here](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)